# Refresh webpage content after running a cronjob on server

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, cron

I have a cronjob on the server which add some new rows in a table and I am showing that data on webpage. I want to refresh that content with updated rows
every time cronjob completes to add new rows. My problem is how do i know that new rows are created in the database so that I could refresh the content.
I am using laravel's kernel schedules for creating cronjob.

Right now I am sending an ajax after every 10 seconds but it seems wrong because there are too many ajax requests going on the server.

Comment: 1 ajax every 10 seconds is not that much depending how many people are updating the browser.

Also is it only one browser on the machine the cron job run or there is a lot of browsers on multiple machines?

Comment: If you are not comfortable with making too many requests, you could try web sockets and listen for the response from the server.

Comment: @MichaelMuryn yes there will be multiple people with multiple browsers

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan will sockets work with cronjobs too?